# Angle incorrect while plotting with dimple.js

Tags: dimple.js

i am plotting a d3 chart. 
    The chart is given at http://dimplejs.org/examples_viewer.html?id=pie_matrix.
    But when i plot the chart with my data in pie chart the total percentage is 99%. Not 100%.

```
    var svg = dimple.newSvg("#ChartName", 590, 400);
        var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
        myChart.setBounds(95, 25, 475, 335);
        var x = myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", "Month");
        x.addOrderRule("mno");
        myChart.addCategoryAxis("y", "AgeGroup");
        var p = myChart.addMeasureAxis("p", "cnt");
        p.tickFormat="02d";
        var pies = myChart.addSeries("event", dimple.plot.pie);
        pies.radius = 25;
        myChart.addLegend(240, 10, 330, 20, "right");
        myChart.draw();


Am using http://dimplejs.org/dist/dimple.v2.1.0.min.js.


Example while i  plot, i get 50% not 50.00% , because of rounding of angle for plotting it is showing wrongly. Can you people please tell how to remove the round of.

The data from database is correct. It is a count like 100,200 etc.while plotting pie with that values it is showing wronly.



Example
--------

Count1 =562
Count2 =62
Count3 =53
Count4 =39  

While Plotting with these values in pie chart i got Count1 = 78%, Count2 = 9%, Count3 = 7%, Count4 = 5%.

Total is 99%.Not 100%.
While finding percentage manually we get upto 2 spaces after .
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the tick format after drawing, that way it won't interfere with the chart drawing but will affect the tooltip.